# How to denote a tensor in terms of matrices product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors

How to write a tensor in terms of a product of matrices?

For example, I have $a \times b$ matrix $F$, and I want to create a 3D $a \times a \times a$ tensor $T$, where

$T_{i,j,k} = \sum_{m=1}^{b} F_{i,m}  F_{j,m}  F_{k,m}$

How should I denote such product in terms of matrix notation?

For example,

$T = FF^T$ is a product which creates
$T_{i,j} = \sum_{m=1}^{b} F_{i,m}  F_{j,m}$.

EDIT: 
I heard that $a_ib_i$ can be used to denote $\sum_i a_i b_i$, can this notation be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a [simple tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_(intrinsic_definition)#Tensor_rank).  We may write this tensor as $F \otimes F \otimes F$.